# ActiveRecord::Base establish connection to Redis

Tags: ruby, activerecord, redis

How do I use the activerecord gem with Redis?

I see all these examples with models and Redis but I keep getting a "not connected" error when I try to use them..

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord does not know how to speak to Redis, only to SQL databases.
To use redis here is a list of gems you can use:

If you want to use redis directly (I think you should): [redis-rb](https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb)
If you really want an ORM: [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects)